# VK sdk android как использовать методы account из документации?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Здравствуйте! Как в VKSdk andnroid выполнять запросы к методам account?

```
    final TextView requestText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
    final VKRequest request = VKApi.account().getProfileInfo(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"first_name,last_name"));
     request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
             super.onComplete(response);

             VKList list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
             if(list!=null) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                     requestText.append("\n" + list.get(i).toString());
                 }
             }   
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(VKError error) {
             super.onError(error);
             requestText.setText(error.toString());
         }
     });
```

На строчку `final VKRequest request = VKApi.account().getProfileInfo(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"first_name,last_name"));` IDE ругается и подсвечивает красным `account()`. Оно и понятно в [vk-android-sdk](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/tree/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/api/methods) отсутствует класс для доступа к методам `account`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загрузка произвольного метода API:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("account.getProfileInfo", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"first_name,last_name"));
```

[Официальная документация, подпункт 5](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk?f=4.1.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)